# How to use web3 to send ETH from wallet A to wallet B through an intermediary Smart Contract?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, cpp-ethereum, bsc, sendtransaction

I want to send eth from 1 wallet address A to wallet B address but through an intermediary Smart contract, what should I do? I don't know how to solve that problem yet.
EX: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe12b37a0103fb38c1e3f75ee536b554505223c9652fb77c90673b3b3fb907a9d

Answer (score 0):

Following code will do the job:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract TestContract {
    function checkBalance(address _address) public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(_address).balance;
    }
    
    function simpleTransfer(address _address) public payable {
        payable(_address).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

Method `simpleTransfer` is transfering ETH to passed address as parameter. You can attach whatever logic you wish now to this method, but make sure you are following the **Checks-Effects-Interactions pattern**. Which basically says - **do not update contract state after after ETH or token transfers**. Contract state should always be updated before the submission of ETH or tokens. [Read more here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.4.24/security-considerations.html#re-entrancy)